# mysql, query how to goup same value and count that value

Tags: mysql

i have data table like that :

```
month   IKU   value
  2     1b      1
  2     1b      1
  1     2a      1
  1     1a      1
```

the results I want like that :

```
month   IKU     value
  2     1b       2
  1     1a,2a    1,1
```

is that possible?

Comment: the first row in the result set is confusing. `2  1b  2`? why not `2   1b  1,1`?

Comment: no it can't be.

Comment: you are grouping the rows based on month?

Comment: yes, i am grouping the rows based on month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` twice along with [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function like below:

```
SELECT 
tmp.month,
GROUP_CONCAT(tmp.IKU) AS IKU,
GROUP_CONCAT(tmp.summedValue) AS value
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        month,
        IKU,
        SUM(value) AS summedValue
    FROM t
    GROUP BY month,IKU
) AS tmp 
GROUP BY tmp.month
ORDER BY tmp.month DESC
```

---

**GROUP_CONCAT() function**

`MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()` function returns a string with concatenated non-NULL value from a group.

Returns NULL when there are no non-NULL values.

---

**Test:**

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `t`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t`;
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `month` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IKU` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of t
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `t` VALUES ('2', '1b', '1');
INSERT INTO `t` VALUES ('2', '1b', '1');
INSERT INTO `t` VALUES ('1', '2a', '1');
INSERT INTO `t` VALUES ('1', '1a', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Didn't get chance to test it as MySQL fiddle isn't working, but the idea is to first `sum(value)` for each combination of `month,iku`. Then use `group_concat` to concatenate the resultset.

```
select month
  ,group_concat(IKU separator ',') 
  ,group_concat(value separator ',')
from 
(select month,IKU,sum(value) as value 
   from Table1 group by month,IKU
) t
group by IKU
```